# Convert a large long in python to unsigned char array

Tags: python, ctypes

Have a python server talking to a C/C++ client.  The client expects an unsigned char array to be passed back so I need a way to convert from a long to an unsigned char* of length 64.

Edit:
My initial thought was to look into the memory for the long and grab 8bit chunks to try and create the needed unsigned chars.  I'm testing that now.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to approach the subject since I need it to be 64 chars long.  Because this is part of a D-H handshake, I need to maintain the long that is being passed so that it is the same on the client side.  I've looked into struct, bytearray, and c_ubyte but with no success.

Comment: Are we talking about a 512-bit integer (64*8 bits)?

Comment: The 64 unsigned char array is converted into an integer later, but must be passed as an unsigned char array. So yes, probably 512 bit, 64 bytes.

Comment: You can write a helper for Python 2 that shifts the byte values into a `bytearray`. It's a bit simpler in Python 3, e.g. `(123456).to_bytes(64, 'big')`.

Comment: @eryksun Awesome.  Just upgraded to python3 just for that.  Put it as an answer so I can accept.  Worked like a charm.